# Postgres still using parallel sequential scan with Index

Tags: postgresql

I have this table (10GB)

```
CREATE TABLE public.target_reports (
    ad_type character varying NOT NULL,
    targetid bigint NOT NULL,
    targeting_type character varying,
    targeting_text character varying,
    targeting_expression character varying,
);
```

With this index on [ad_type, targeting_type]

```
CREATE INDEX index_target_reports_on_ad_type_and_targeting_type ON public.target_reports USING btree (ad_type, targeting_type);
```

but when running this query

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT

    targeting_text,
    targeting_type,
    ad_type
FROM target_reports
WHERE NOT (ad_type = 'abc' AND targeting_type = 'EXPRESSION')
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```

I see is still using a Parallel Seq Scan. Shouldn't you use an index scan?

```
Group  (cost=3239008.07..4090004.93 rows=3026465 width=58) (actual time=102029.238..126678.856 rows=3949093 loops=1)
  Group Key: targeting_text, targeting_type, ad_type, query
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=3239008.07..4029475.63 rows=6052930 width=58) (actual time=102029.234..124407.763 rows=5451372 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Group  (cost=3238008.04..3329817.29 rows=3026465 width=58) (actual time=101829.781..114504.982 rows=1817124 loops=3)
              Group Key: targeting_text, targeting_type, ad_type, query
              ->  Sort  (cost=3238008.04..3256369.89 rows=7344740 width=58) (actual time=101829.752..112707.834 rows=4149214 loops=3)
                    Sort Key: targeting_text, targeting_type, ad_type, query
                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 295216kB
                    Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 294960kB
                    Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 294496kB
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on target_reports  (cost=0.00..1848110.61 rows=7344740 width=58) (actual time=0.285..29329.998 rows=4149214 loops=3)
                          Filter: (((ad_type)::text <> 'sd'::text) OR ((targeting_type)::text <> 'TARGETING_EXPRESSION'::text))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 5894394
Planning Time: 3.750 ms
Execution Time: 126859.195 ms
```

Comment: `targeting_text` is not in the index. It is also the first expression in `GROUP BY`. Even if the index were used, the base table would still have to be consulted, just to grab the targeting_text.

Comment: Also: there appears to be no primary key, and `{targeting_type, targeting_text, targeting_expression }` look highly correlated to me. Maybe do some data modelling first? [ What is the combined cardinality of `{targeting_type, targeting_text, targeting_expression }` ?]

Comment: work_mem is also too small for sorting in memory, the database is forced to use disk. Give it shot with lets say 500MB: SET work_mem TO '500MB'; And use explain again to see the difference

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL thinks that a sequential scan is faster, and it is probably right: the condition excludes only about half of the data, too little to make an index scan perform much better, and the sequential scan is probably faster due to parallelization.

If you want to reduce resource consumption rather than response time, set `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` to 0 to disable parallel query. Then PostgreSQL *might* choose a bitmap index scan, even though the performance will not be much different from a sequential scan.